# One shopping cart price rule for one time use by a single customer only

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to make a shopping cart price rule which can be used only once by a single customer/user only after then that coupon can not be used by the same user.

I am new to magento and have to implement this in my project and did a lot of research for this but could not find any solution.

I also want to know how to make the coupon to be used by all the group of users i.e. Not Logged In, General, Wholesale, Retailer.

Basically, the coupon should be used once only by one customer/user.

If anyone has done this then please help me.

I am using Magento community 1.9.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a rule there is an option: "Uses per Customer" which is a usage limit enforced for logged in customers only, simply set it to '1'. To select multiple customer groups please use "shift" key and select all the groups you need.